# How to compare two commits in Bitbucket server

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Is there a way to compare two commits in Bitbucket **server**?

For bitbucket cloud, you can enter a URL as follows into your browser: https://bitbucket.org/OWNER/PROJECT/branches/compare/commit2..commit1

(per this discussion: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/4779/ability-to-diff-between-any-two-commits).

The same thing (as well as lots of other functionality) does not seem to work in Bitbucket server as I get a 404 error.

Comment: Coming in Bitbucket Server 6.3 it seems https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-2550

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `https://bitbucket.org/OWNER/PROJECT/branches/compare/commit2..commit1` not supported on Bitbucket Server.

You can use REST API that utilizes to diff arbitrary commits. [Here](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.3/stash-rest.html#idp257216) is the documentation on that REST API endpoint.

The command line for diffs is: "git diff A B", where it shows the changes from A to B. The REST URL looks like

```
/rest/api/latest/projects/KEY/repos/slug/changes?since=A&until=B
```

(where A and B have the same relevance). That will list all the files that changed.

You can call /rest/api/latest/projects/KEY/repos/slug/diff/?since=A&until=B. Write the file path you want the diff for after "/diff/" and before "?since".

*Example:*

```
https://mybitbucket.com/rest/api/latest/projects/STASH/repos/stash/changes?since=689fcf1017dc944ab976433a9ead8f2912d83622&until=a222a1f58c17f9164eb498eeaadde94675a49467}}

https://mybitbucket.com/rest/api/latest/projects/STASH/repos/stash/diff/dao-impl/src/main/java/com/atlassian/stash/internal/pull/HibernateRescopeRequestDao.java?since=689fcf1017dc944ab976433a9ead8f2912d83622&until=a222a1f58c17f9164eb498eeaadde94675a49467
```

You will have to include a path after {{/diff}}. You can't just ask for the entire diff.

Comment: I assume the rest api response is just a git diff formatted as unified diff - no different from just diffing from cmd line, right? What's needed IMO is an html-formatted pretty diff like in the Bitbucket server UI.

Answer (score 1):

This is supported in Bitbucket Data Center and Server 6.3 although the URL is different.

To compare revisions and see the URL:

1. Navigate to the repository where you want to compare revisions.
2. From the sidebar, click Compare.
3. In the Compare page, from both the Source and Destination dropdown, select any combination of branches, tags, or commits.

Here are the [full instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/compare-branches-tags-and-commits-970595881.html).